# Is $L^{\infty}([0, 1]; \mathbb{R}^{n})$ densely embedded in some Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, optimal-control

I'm solving a control problem and I have a question. Is it possible to show that $L^{\infty}([0, 1]; \mathbb{R}^{n})$ is densely embedded in some Hilbert space?

Comment: What have you attempted to show/prove this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987943/embedding-of-lp-spaces